# How to set up a Java runner on C9

Tags: java, cloud9-ide

I added the default java runners from here https://docs.c9.io/v1.0/docs/custom-runners and the folder names match the runners but I get this error 
"Could not find or load main class Hello World" when I try to run the Hello World program. [This is the folder hierarchy of my project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEHJg.png)

Comment: Can you get your java app to run without the runners, using the terminal without problems?